# Spell Checking in Programmer's Notepad

Tags: text-editor, spell-checking

Is there a way to add spell checking to Programmer's Notepad? This one feature is a major make or break for me, and otherwise PNotepad is my favorite to use on windows (KATE on linux).

Answer (score 2):

Did a quick search and found this topic on Programmer Notepads forum: http://pnotepad.org/forums/topic/604

The script can be found: http://scriptshare.rocketmonkeys.com/script/14

Answer (score 0):

Generally spell checkers and IDEs don't get along.  There are too many things in programming languages that aren't actually words.  I would think a spell checker would just end up telling you that most of your code is misspelled...

Comment: Actually PN is neither an IDE nor is it true what you say. Visual Assist X for VS will happily point out all kinds of spelling issues in code comments, for example. Since plugins to IDEs usually have knowledge of the context (such as comment vs. code), they are very much suitable to supply spell-checking even in IDEs.